# Openlayers can't modify drawn features

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I would like to make a chance for modifying my features in OpenLayers.  So far I can only drag them across the map, but I can't change their shapes at all when drawn.

[image]

In the picture above you can spot the blue dot, which just moves along the shape border but is not able to modify it.

I tried to modify my code by using this example:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-geodesic.html

and my piece of code looks like this:

```
var modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
 features: selectInteraction.getFeatures({
   if (modifyPoint[0] === center[0] && modifyPoint[1] === center[1]) {
    first = transform(polygon[0], projection, 'EPSG:4326');
    last = transform(
      polygon[(polygon.length - 1) / 2],
      projection,
      'EPSG:4326'
    );
     radius = getDistance(first, last) / 2;
   } else {
     first = transform(center, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
     last = transform(modifyPoint, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
     radius = getDistance(first, last);
   }
   const circle = circular(
    transform(center, projection, 'EPSG:4326'),
    radius,
    128
   );
   circle.transform('EPSG:4326', projection);
   geometries[0].setCoordinates(circle.getCoordinates());
   // save changes to be applied at the end of the interaction
   modifyGeometry.setGeometries(geometries);
  ),
});
var translateInteraction = new ol.interaction.Translate({
 features: selectInteraction.getFeatures()
});

var setActiveEditing = function(active) {
    selectInteraction.getFeatures().clear();
    selectInteraction.setActive(active);
    modifyInteraction.setActive(active);
    translateInteraction.setActive(active);
};
setActiveEditing(true);
```

and the full fiddle is available here:

https://jsfiddle.net/2yj1ae04/

How can I make these features editable after drawing them in OpenLayers Map?

**UPDATE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/bsqzc31j/

This is the code I used recently, it's exactly the same effect but no error:

https://jsfiddle.net/bsqzc31j/

```
var modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  features: selectInteraction.getFeatures()
});
```

full situation:

http://test.mkrgeo-blog.com/

**UPDATE:**

I recently tried this code:

```
    var modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: selectInteraction.getFeatures(),
    deleteCondition: function(event) {
    return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&
    ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
    }
   });
```

which works on this map:

http://www.scgis.net/api/ol/v3.6.0/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html

but in my case is still the same.

It does work, when I completely remove/switch off the  new `ol.interaction.Translate({` However in this event i am unable to drag my features.

**UPDATE III:**

After aplying the codes from answer 1 I have situation like this:
The feature still can't be modfied at all, so the codes defined in my ol.interaction.Modify()  don't work:

```
 var modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
 features: selectInteraction.getFeatures(),
 deleteCondition: function(event) {
 return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&
    ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
 }

});
 map.addInteraction(modifyInteraction);
```

where I defined both adding the new nodes and deleting existing ones by holding the `Shift` button.

In this situation, when I have the `ol.interaction.Translate` defined:

```
 var translateInteraction = new ol.interaction.Translate({
   condition: function (event) {
   return (
    ol.events.condition.primaryAction(event) &&
    ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly(event)
   );
   },
 features: selectInteraction.getFeatures(),
```

});
map.addInteraction(translateInteraction);

the edition of my features is simply blocked. I can drag them but I can't edit them. Since I hold the Alt button I can drag the blue dot away from the object, but nothing happens. Is there any way I can combine both `ol.interaction.Modify({`  and  `new ol.interaction.Translate({`  together, making all these options listed below working>

- dragging object
- creating a new node
- deleting an existing node

I tried to do it by the holding Shift button:

```
 var dragFeature = function(evt){
   if(evt.keyCode == 16){
    var translateInteraction = new ol.interaction.Translate({
     features: selectInteraction.getFeatures(),
    });
  };
```

but I am getting an error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: translateInteraction is not defined**

This means that the translateInteraction variable is not global anymore, because it has been created inside another variable.

Comment: The fiddle seems not to work

Comment: Hi, It won't work, as it includes the JavaScript code only. I just placed it in a whole in order to get you around with pure JS code.

Comment: The posted code has syntax  errors stating in the 2nd line: `features: selectInteraction.getFeatures({ if (modifyPoint[0] === center[0]` And it is also wrong in your linked fiddle.

Comment: so how to fix it then?

Comment: Initialize your modify interaction like this: `var modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({ features: selectInteraction.getFeatures() })`. The other code you posted above needs to go elsewhere.

Comment: I have updated my query, see it below the "UPDATE" comment.  Your advice brought me to the very beginning.

Comment: In http://test.mkrgeo-blog.com/ both your modify and translate interactions have the same default condition. You cannot modify because the translate handles the event first,

Comment: Yes, but what does it mean. I don't understand this code enough. Is there any change to change it?

Comment: Just a question: why specifically draw-and-modify-geodesic rather than just using draw-and-modify-features? https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html

Comment: I can't answer this question frankly. I just seek out the method, which will work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In http://test.mkrgeo-blog.com/ there is a conflict between the Modify and Translate interactions as they use the same default condition.  You could distinguish between them so Translate only accepts mouse action while the `Ctrl` key is pressed

```
  new ol.interaction.Translate({
    condition: function (event) {
      return (
        ol.events.condition.primaryAction(event) &&
        ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly(event)
      );
    },
    ...
```

and Modify does not work when `Ctrl` is pressed (but still allows `Alt` to delete vertices)

```
  new ol.interaction.Modify({
    condition: function (event) {
      return (
        ol.events.condition.primaryAction(event) &&
        !ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly(event)
      );
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Still not working. However your code makes sense anyway. Maybe should I apply the ol.interaction.Modify and ol.interaction.Translate for every single feature defined in the code?

Comment: I have polylines and polygons that are editable and I did not make use of ol.interaction.Translate so I do not think it is necessary to use it.

Comment: Yes, I have switched off the ol.interaction.Translate and it's better. I can change the shapes by addding new nodes. However I still can't delete these nodes. Moreover if I change the shape if corcle or rectangle , they loose their initial shapes.

Comment: And when the translateinteraction is removed I can't drag the shapes as I could before.

Comment: That is the expected behaviour for those interactions.  Modify changes the geometry, translate moves the entire geometry.  With a lot of customising you can restrict modify to scaling and rotating https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-scale-and-rotate.html

Comment: Yes, but having your code I can't still modify my shapes. If I remove translation, then I am able to modify objects but I can't drag them. Is there something I could edit? I saw, in the ol.Modify library, that dragging should come as the default, but it doesn't.

Comment: I have updated my query again. Are you able to help me?

Answer (score -1):

I think maybe two things. 1. you are not targeting the correct source when you are trying to modify and 2. not adding modify interaction to the map. see example below.

```
const style // just an array of style objects 
const source = new VectorSource();
const vector = new VectorLayer({
    map:///map object
    source: source,
    style: style
})

const modify = new Modify({source: source});
map.addInteraction(modify);

//another way to get the selected item
const select = new Select({
    style:style,
    layers:vector,
})
select.on('select', (event)=> {
   this.selected = event.target.getFeatures().item(0);//global variable
})

//add this 
const translate = new Translate({
  features: select.getFeatures(),
});
map.addInteraction(translate);
```

Comment: I have got all of them. I have:  condition: ol.events.condition.click, instead of source:source

Comment: I have updated my answer to include using the select.on() method to get the selected item as you may find it interesting as an alternative to ol.events.condition.click.

Comment: Ok the layer.this.layer can be appplied for more than 1 layer or should I specify the certain layer?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer, it should be the vector layer..

Comment: Now I have an error: uncaught TypeError: t.indexOf is not a function for aray.js 92

Comment: are you referencing your map object in your VectorLayer?

Comment: yes, one of drawing layer as defined in my jfdiddle or link provided.

Comment: Please see my updated question and problem description. I wish I could bountied your answer within 5 hours.

Comment: Sorted! Just needed to switch off the translate option.