# OpenLayers I am not able to drag the custom features

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Following the query here:

[Openlayers can't modify drawn features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69313925/openlayers-cant-modify-drawn-features)

I have built some code, which allowes me to edit nodes of my drawn features:

```
 var modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
 features: selectInteraction.getFeatures(),
 deleteCondition: function(event) {
 return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&
    ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
 }
});
map.addInteraction(modifyInteraction);
```

However I have lost the option for dragging my features, which is defined by this code:

```
 var translateInteraction = new ol.interaction.Translate({
features: selectInteraction.getFeatures(),
});
map.addInteraction(translateInteraction);
```

The  `new ol.interaction.Translate({`   has been switched off, otherwise I am not able to edit my features, but I can only drag them.

Is there any chance to make my features draggable when I can edit them like defined in the code `new ol.interaction.Modify({`  above?

My full JSfiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/g196cqoa/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition option to the translate interaction to only interact when ctrl key is pressed.

```js
var modifyInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  features: selectInteraction.getFeatures(),
  deleteCondition: function(event) {
    return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&
      ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
  },
});
map.addInteraction(modifyInteraction);

const translate = new ol.interaction.Translate({
  features: selectInteraction.getFeatures(),
  condition: function (event) {
    return ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly(event) &&
      ol.events.condition.primaryAction(event);
  },
});
map.addInteraction(translate);
```

Alternatively, if you add the translate interaction before the modify interaction it should allow you to drag polygons as long as you stay away from the edges. This won't work with lines and points. as there is no area where the geometry cannot be modified.

The order in which the interactions are added to the maps interaction collection determines whether the modify interaction is allowed see and handle the events before the translate interaction handles them

Comment: //Alternatively, if you add the translate interaction before the modify interaction it should allow you to drag polygons as long as you stay away from the edges

This works for me. Thankd you.